# Robots.txt: Disallow subdirectory but allow directory

Tags: robots.txt

I want to allow crawling of files in:

```
/directory/
```

but not crawling of files in:

```
/directory/subdirectory/
```

Is the correct robots.txt instruction:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /subdirectory/
```

I'm afraid that if I disallowed /directory/subdirectory/
that I would be disallowing crawling of all files in /directory/ which I do not want to do, so am I correct in using:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /subdirectory/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've overthinking it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory/subdirectory/
```

is correct.

Comment: Isn't User-agent: * Disallow: /directory/subdirectory/ going to remove any files in /directory/ ? I still want the files in directory in the search index but not the files in the subdirectory  /directory/subdirectory/

Comment: No, why would it do that?  It's disallowing the subdirectory, not the parent.

Comment: Well...as part of my research many people on the internet are saying that disallowing /directory/subdirectory/ disallows all files in /directory/ also so that it is necessary to do:User-agent: * Disallow: /directory/subdirectory/ Allow: /directory/index.html i'm just trying to find out which is correct?

Comment: @user, what resource says that?  Either you misunderstood, or they're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory/subdirectory/
```

Spiders aren't stupid, they can parse a path :)

Comment: I don't understand the implecation of what you're saying.

Comment: @user If you do `cd /directory/subdirectory/` does it take you to `directory`? No, the significant folder is the last in the path, in this case the `subdirectory`.